# How the value 3 is passed to 'x' to instantiate the template function 'f'?

Tags: c++, templates

How does the compiler pass the value 3 to the non-type parameter `x` ?

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Type, size_t x>
void f(Type (&a)[x])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        a[i] = i;
        std::cout << a[i] << '\n';
    }
}

int main()
{
    int v[3];
    f(v);
}
```

Comment: Template type deduction

Comment: x is of type size_t so it has a defined type at compile time

Answer (score 0):

Templates allow both typenames and integer types, like `size_t`.

For integer types, the template function is initialized with the value (which must be known at compile time), not a type.

The compiler knows that function `f()` expects an argument of type `Type (&a)[x]` and checks if there's any combination of `Type` and `x` that would work for the argument `v` that you passed.

This process is called *template type deduction*.

Comment: But the call `f(v)` doesn't have the template second argument. How is the `x` deducted from this call ?

Comment: The call to `f(v)` doesn't provide *either* template argument.  The compiler deduces both (`int` and `3`) by analyzing what `v` is.

Comment: Do you know where this construction `int v[3]; int (&t)[3] = v; f(t);` is supported in the Standard ? I'm talking specifically about the expression `int(&t)[3] = v;`.